The definition of the primitive vectors?
I was studying Solid State Physics by Kittel, when he defined the primitive transilation vectors he mentioned that: "The lattice is said to be primitive if any two points from which the atomic
arrangement looks the same always satisfy (1) with a suitable choice of the integers $u_i$. This statement defines the primitive translation vectors $a_i$"
where equation (1):$$\vec{r'} = \vec{r} + u_1 \vec{a_1} + u_2 \vec{a_2} + u_3 \vec{a_3}$$
i can say from the above discussion that the primitive vectors are any vector that satisfy the transilation operation.
I have seen also the definition of the primitive vectors by H.E.Hall textbook, he mentioned that: "The distances and directions of the nearest lattice points along the x and y axes are specified by the lattice vectors (the primitive vectors) $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$."
So the question is how these two difintions are compatible with each other, and is it right that the primitive vectors are the shortest or nearest vectors that define the primitive unit cell as mentioned by H.E.Hall textbook above ?!

In practice the choice of primitive unit cell is a matter of convention, as long as the vectors $\vec a_i$, $1\leq i\leq 3$ actually generate the entire translational symmetry group of the lattice (and not just a subgroup of it.)  It so happens that choosing vectors with smallest norm (and that are oriented consistently with a right-handed coordinate system) results in figures (e.g. unit cells and Brillouin zones) with the "nicest" appearance, at least to a conventionally trained physicist.

Thanks for clarifying, it makes sense now.

Note: the symmetry group generally includes rotations as well as translations (e.g. in a cubic or hexagonal close-packed lattice.) The primitive vectors $a_i$ should generate the entire group of translation symmetries.
